# Best way to display a jpeg stream in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, image, jpeg, display

I'm trying to display in visual studio a jpeg stream sent by a camera. The data format is in hexadecimal and is coming with the standard jpeg header.

Well I know how to display a jpeg image so my plan is to read the the data save it as a jpeg file using the file I/O functions and then after display it in a form. Every time that comes a new image the one being displayed is replaced (like a refresh).

Would it be the correct approach for this? or is there any other function or way to achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: This seems to depend on the type of form - and will vary from framework to framework, but it sounds like a good plan A.

Comment: Maybe add code that shows an image from a file? You can [edit] your question to add this info.

Comment: _"The data format is in hexadecimal "_ Are you sure that's not just how you're representing it visually? It would be very strange for any raw data stream to be transmitted in ASCII form. More likely it's a [binary] stream of actual data bytes.

Answer (score -1):

You can treat the data as a stream of image files, but it is hard on your disk drive and not terribly efficient. It's the sort of program which is fine for casual use, but likely to be unacceptable in any professional environment.

You receive a binary stream of data, so decode it to an rgb buffer, then display the data, on Windows by using the BitBlt function to write out pixels directly to the screen.

Take my JPEG decoder from here https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyxrc/tree/master/src if you don't have your own. You can trivially modify it to take a bitstream rather than an stdlib FILE *.

Comment: Thanks Malcolm for your help, but to decode the data, first I have to "create" a jpeg file from the incoming stream and then decode it to a rgb buffer and then display it which is similar flow I was planning to use, with the only difference that I display the jpeg without decode it, I'm not seeing clearly the advantage in terms of efficiency, maybe I'm confused but, could you please explain me what would be the advantage?

Comment: Is the data coming in as raw ppm (rgb) values or as a JPEG-encoded stream?

Comment: It is coming as a JPEG encoded stream, e.g. I can print and save the incoming  hex values in a text file, then change the extension to jpeg and see the image.

Comment: Ok, I think got the point, I'll go to try to decode the jpeg file to rgb values and then display them without creating a file, thanks.